# Neo4j Cypher Relationships bulk update properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-driver, neo4j-javascript

I am hoping someone can help me figure out why this bulk update to relationship properties is not working from the given dataset. The id value in the dataset is the neo4j ID of the relationship. `tq`, `rpc` and `weight` are the properties on it.

```
var batchUpdate = [{"id":281,"tq":8,"rpc":2.4,"weight":84},{"id":283,"tq":5,"rpc":1.25,"weight":10},
{"id":286,"tq":4,"rpc":3.2,"weight":5}];

var nQuery = WITH {batchUpdate} AS stats UNWIND stats AS s MATCH ()-[k:BELONGS_TO]-() WHERE id(k)=s.id SET k.weight=s.weight, k.rpc=s.rpc, k.tq=s.tq;

session
.run(nQuery,{batchUpdate:batchUpdate})
.then(function (result) {
console.log('updated');
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log('neo4j stats update error ' + error);
});
```

I get no errors, it falls into success function, but no properties actually update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the official neo4j Javascript driver, you should use the [neo4j.int()](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type) function to wrap an integer value being passed via a parameter, to work around the fact that Javascript does not support 64-bit integers (whereas that is what neo4j uses). By default, the Javascript driver converts integers in parameters to floats.

A float will not be considered equal to an equivalent integer.

Try changing your array, like this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

...

var batchUpdate = [
  {"id":neo4j.int(281),"tq":neo4j.int(8),"rpc":2.4, "weight":neo4j.int(84)},
  {"id":neo4j.int(283),"tq":neo4j.int(5),"rpc":1.25,"weight":neo4j.int(10)},
  {"id":neo4j.int(286),"tq":neo4j.int(4),"rpc":3.2, "weight":neo4j.int(5)}
];
```

Comment: Wow, great answer.  Worked perfectly!  Thank you :)